# Нестандартная геометрия блока: полукруг сверху блока

Tags: html, css

Необходимо сделать блок именно такой формы, только без бордера в том месте, где круг и блок соприкасаются. Первое, что пришло в голову, - это поместить круг за блоком, а вот как справиться с border'ом - не знаю. Конечно, можно применить графику, но как-то не хочется. Есть ли другие варианты решения?

```css
.promo-cards__item {
    position: relative;
    width: -webkit-calc(33.3% - 18px);
    width: calc(33.3% - 18px);
    height: 250px;
    margin: 40px 9px;
    padding: 40px 3.25em;
    background-color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #e6e6e6
}

.promo-cards__item:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: -32px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    overflow: auto;
    margin: auto;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    content: '';
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
    z-index: -1
}
```

```html
<div class="promo-cards__item">
    <div class="promo-cards__img promo-cards__img1"></div>
    <a href="" class="promo-cards__button"></a>
    <span class="promo-cards__headline">text</span>
    <p class="promo-cards__description">text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: А блок закрашен не будет? Он будет белого цвета?

Comment: @stepankasyanenko блок будет белого цвета, внутри него будет картинка и текст, но за самим блоком - фон серого цвета

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно решить разными способами.

Вот вам для примера два способа:

Пример на [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/p4ayuts5/).

```css
.promo-cards__item {
  position: relative;
  width: -webkit-calc(33.3% - 18px);
  width: calc(33.3% - 18px);
  height: 250px;
  margin: 40px 9px;
  padding: 40px 3.25em;
  background-color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
  border-top: none;
}

.promo-cards__item .line {
  position: absolute;
  border-top: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
  height: 0;
  width: calc((100% - 146px) / 2)
}

.promo-cards__item .line.left-top {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.promo-cards__item .line.right-top {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.promo-cards__item:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: -32px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  margin: auto;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  content: '';
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
  z-index: -1
}
```

```html
<div class="promo-cards__item">
  <div class='line left-top'></div>
  <div class='line right-top'></div>
  <div class="promo-cards__img promo-cards__img1"></div>
  <a href="" class="promo-cards__button"></a>
  <span class="promo-cards__headline">text</span>
  <p class="promo-cards__description">text</p>
</div>
```

Пример на [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/z8qwjms2/).

```css
.promo-cards__item {
  position: relative;
  width: -webkit-calc(33.3% - 18px);
  width: calc(33.3% - 18px);
  height: 250px;
  background-color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
  z-index: 1;
  margin: 40px 9px;
  min-width:200px;
}

.promo-cards__item_content {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.promo-cards__item:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: -32px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  margin: auto;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  content: '';
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="promo-cards__item">
  <div class="promo-cards__item_content">
    <div class="promo-cards__img promo-cards__img1"></div>
    <a href="" class="promo-cards__button"></a>
    <span class="promo-cards__headline">text</span>
    <p class="promo-cards__description">text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Каждый из вариантов имеет свои плюсы и минусы.